# Replacing button on .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three buttons that I'm trying to swap out with each other on .click(): "play", "pause", and "resume". The first button swap works from #play —> #pause, but after that this #pause button does not respond.

http://jsfiddle.net/YzVJN/

Any help would be appreciated!

```
$("#start").click(function() {
    $("#start").replaceWith("<button id=\"pause\">Pause</button>");
});

$("#pause").click(function() {
    $("#pause").replaceWith("<button id=\"resume\">Resume</button>");
});

$("#resume").click(function() {
    $("#resume").replaceWith("<button id=\"pause\">Pause</button>");
});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply change the text and maybe add a `data-` attribute to tell me more about the current state, as the text, in a future version could be swap with a localization.

```
<button class="btn-action" data-action="pause">Pause</button>
```

and then

```
$(".btn-action").click(function() {
    var currentAction = $(this).data("action"),
        nextAction = "";

    switch (currentAction)
    {
      case "play": nextAction = "pause"; break;
      case "pause": nextAction = "resume"; break;
      case "resume": nextAction = "play"; break;
    }

    $(this).text(nextAction).data("action", nextAction);
});
```

When you have a localization settings, you can easily swap the `text()` for something like

```
$(this).text(actionLocalization[nextAction])
```

**Always doubt your own code** when you're repeating yourself...

---

Here's a simple example: http://jsbin.com/ehonob/1/edit/

Comment: +1 for the 'Always doubt your own code when you're repeating yourself' comment

Comment: This is beautiful, I would never thought of using a case like this. +1

Comment: Oh, I was doubting it. Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you probably don't want to recreate DOM elements all the time. Have the all in the HTML in the first place, then hide and show the ones you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/YzVJN/4/

```
$("#start").click(function() {
    $("#start").hide();
    $("#pause").show();
});

$("#pause").click(function() {
    $("#pause").hide();
    $("#resume").show();
});

$("#resume").click(function() {
    $("#resume").hide();
    $("#pause").show();
});​
```

If you do want to recreate DOM elements, the elements are going to be new ones each time, so selecting `$("resume")` when first running the script isn't going to return anything - in this case, do what the others have suggested and use something like `on('click', '#pause', ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `on()` with event delegation:

```
$("body").on("click", "#start", function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<button id=\"pause\">Pause</button>");
}).on("click", "#pause", function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<button id=\"resume\">Resume</button>");
}).on("click", "#resume", function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<button id=\"pause\">Pause</button>");
});​
```

Note, instead of `body` you may use any other *static* parent element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YzVJN/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your elements don't exist at the time that you are setting up the binding.

You need to use "live", "delegate", or "on" as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", "#pause", function() {
    $("#pause").replaceWith("<button id=\"resume\">Resume</button>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to remove and add elements then can do this and re-register handlers each time.

```
$("#start").click(function() {
    $("#start").replaceWith("<button id=\"pause\">Pause</button>");
    $("#pause").click(function() {
        replaceWithResume();
    }); 
});

function replaceWithResume(){
    $("#pause").replaceWith("<button id=\"resume\">Resume</button>");
    $("#resume").click( function() { replaceWithPause() } );
}

function replaceWithPause(){
    $("#resume").replaceWith("<button id=\"pause\">Pause</button>");
    $("#pause").click( function() { replaceWithResume() } );
}
​
```